# Method Illuminate\Http\Request::tbl_usuario does not exist

Tags: laravel

Me encuentro realizando el sistema de roles en laravel y me encontre con ese problema en el proceso, tengo entendido que se llama al modelo pero no tengo claro por que me dice que no existe.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class loginController extends Controller
  {
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $request->tbl_usuario()->authorizeRoles('metrologo');
    $credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'password');


    if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        return view('lab');
    }else{
        return @error;
    }
}
```

}

El error ocurre justo al ingresar la linea del request porque de lo contrario el programa funciona normal. En mi modelo "tbl_usuario" tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
class tbl_usuario extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
use Authenticatable;
public $table="tbl_usuario";
public $timestamps=false;

public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

public function authorizeRoles($roles){
    if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
        return true;
    }
    abort(401,'This action is unauthorized');
}
public function hasAnyRole($roles){
    if(is_array($roles)){
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
            return true;
            }
        }
    }else{
        if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
public function hasRole($role){
    if($this->roles()->where('name',$role)->first()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Lo hago de esa manera porque tengo entendido que así accedo al usuario que realizo la petición, estoy equivocado? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Lo hice de la manera que me dices y me sale el siguiente error = Non-static method App\tbl_usuario::authorizeRoles() should not be called statically

Comment: Lo que busco es que si el usuario tiene el rol de metrologo me redireccione a la vista en este caso "lab" , a lo mejor me este confundiendo, estoy aprendiendo laravel hasta ahora @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Ok, es eso mismo que te decía, hasta que el usuario no esté logueado (autenticado) no puedes chequear que rol tiene, pues no sabes que usuario és. En realidad nunca lo hice así, pero puedes probar con `if(tbl_usuario::find(Auth::id())->authorizeRoles('metrologo')) return view('lab');` después del if attemt

Comment: Okey hice el cambio pero me sale un error de sql, no tengo idea de porque, a lo mejor en el seeder o al momento de migrar falle en algo, pero creo que lo optimo es hacer otra pregunta no? @porloscerrosΨ